# Странное поведение при преобразовании объекта в JSON

Tags: javascript, promise, json-encode

При преобразовании объекта в JSON некоторые свойства вложенных объектов куда-то исчезают:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот js-код:

```
   ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap, myPlacemark, routes = [], distanses = {};

function init() {
  myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 7
  });

  var points = {
    "1": {
      address: "\u041b\u0443\u0433\u0430",
      lat: "58.7372200",
      lng: "29.8452800",
      old_point: "yes"
    },
    "2": {
      address: "\u0421\u0430\u043d\u043a\u0442-\u041f\u0435\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433",
      lat: "59.939095",
      lng: "30.315868",
      old_point: "yes"
    },
    "3": {
      address: "\u041f\u0441\u043a\u043e\u0432"
    },
    "4": {
      address: "\u0412\u0435\u043b\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0439 \u041d\u043e\u0432\u0433\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0434"
    }
  };
  $("#run").click(function() {
    for (let point in points) {
      if (points[point]["lat"]) {
        // console.log(point+': '+points[point]['lng']);
      } else {
        var latlng = $("input[name=point" + point + "]").val();
        var latlng_arr = latlng.split(" ");
        points[point]["lat"] = latlng_arr[1];
        points[point]["lng"] = latlng_arr[0];
      }
    }
    var matrix = {};
    matrix.fnum = false;
    matrix.rows = {};
    var asd = [];
    for (let matrix_row in points) {
      matrix.rows[matrix_row] = {};
      distanses[matrix_row] = {};
      matrix.rows[matrix_row]["row_obj"] = points[matrix_row];
      for (let matrix_col in points) {
        if (points[matrix_row]["old_point"] && points[matrix_col]["old_point"])
          continue;
        matrix.rows[matrix_row][matrix_col] = {};
        matrix.rows[matrix_row][matrix_col]["col_obj"] = points[matrix_col];
        if (matrix_row === matrix_col) {
          distanses[matrix_row][matrix_col] = 0;
        } else {
          // distanses[matrix_row][matrix_col] = calcDistanse(matrix, matrix_row, matrix_col);
          asd.push(calcDistanse(matrix, matrix_row, matrix_col));
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(asd);
    Promise.all(asd).then(items => {
      // console.log(items);
      let full = 0
      items.forEach(route => {
        myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
        console.log(route.getLength());
        full += route.getLength();
      })
      console.log('full', full)
    });
  });
}

function calcDistanse(matrix, matrix_row, matrix_col) {
  // console.log(matrix);
  var row_obj_lat = +matrix.rows[matrix_row]["row_obj"]["lat"],
    row_obj_lng = +matrix.rows[matrix_row]["row_obj"]["lng"],
    col_obj_lat = +matrix.rows[matrix_row][matrix_col]["col_obj"]["lat"],
    col_obj_lng = +matrix.rows[matrix_row][matrix_col]["col_obj"]["lng"];
  return ymaps.route([[row_obj_lat, row_obj_lng], [col_obj_lat, col_obj_lng]], {
    mapStateAutoApply: true
  });
}
```

Весь код приложения можно посмотреть [тут](https://codepen.io/sidredin/pen/WjzWxL).
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем может быть связано такое странное поведение? Есть подозрение, что это связано с промисами, так как остальные свойства, присвоенные вне промис-блоков (блоков, связанных с промисами) - сохранились.
И, конечно же, хотелось бы услышать советы, как решить эту проблему. 2 дня бьюсь над ней - и никак не могу решить.

Answer (score 1):

Это не у JSON странное поведение. Это особенность инспектора в браузере. Когда Вы в консоль выводите объект, то инспектор показывает его текущее состояние. Т.е. когда Вы выводили его в первой строке ф-и он действительно для тройки содержал {"3":0}. Но позже в программе значение для тройки изменилось, и инспектор показывает новое значение - объект. В третьей строке функции вы объект превратили в строку, поэтому это фиксированное значение является более объективным на момент выполнения.